# 404 when trying to redirect to HTML Page

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, next.js

I'm trying to go from a JSX page to an HTML page, but I always get an error when I try to do so. Always a 404 page saying it doesn't exist. It's as if it doesn't exist although I have it clearly in my files and in the same directory.

games.jsx

```
import React from "react";
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import moment from 'moment';
import Link from 'next/link';

export default function Home() {
    const[dataResponse, setdataResponse] = useState([]);
    useEffect(() => {
        async function getPageData() {
            const apiUrlEndpoint = 'http://localhost:3000/api/games';
            const response = await fetch(apiUrlEndpoint);
            const res = await response.json();
            console.log(res.games);
            setdataResponse(res.games);
        }
        getPageData();
    }, []);
    
    return (
        <div className='bg-gray-100 min-h-screen'>
            <a href="newgame.html">Click to Add New Game Product.</a>
            {dataResponse.map((games) => {
                var d = new Date(games.DateWhenAdded);
                var now = moment(d).format('l');
                return (
                    <div key= {games.ProductID}>
                        <div>{games.ProductName}</div>
                    <div>
                        <img src={games.ProductImage} width="400" height="400" alt=""/>
                    </div>
                        <div>
                            {games.ProductDescription}
                        </div>
                    <div>
                         Product added on: {now}
                    </div>
                    <div>
                        Product price: ${games.ProductPrice}
                    </div>
                </div>   
             )
            })}
    </div>
);
}
```

And this is the form I'm trying to redirect to. It's called "newgame.html"

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang = "en">
<head>
<title>
New Game Addition
</title>
</head>
<body>
<form method="post" action="dbcon.php">
    <input type="number" name="ProductID" placeholder="Product ID">
    <input type="text" name="ProductName" placeholder="Name of Product.">
    <input type="text" name="ProductDescription" placeholder="Describe the Product.">
    <input type="file" name="ProductImage" placeholder="Put in Image">
    <input type="date" name="DateWhenAdded" placeholder="01/01/2001">
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="SUBMIT">
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

If you can give me any suggestions on what I should try, that would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put the `newgame.html` file into your [public folder](https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/static-file-serving)...

> This folder is also useful for `robots.txt`, `favicon.ico`, Google Site Verification, and any other static files (**including `.html`**)!

and use the following

```html
<a href="/newgame.html">Click to Add New Game Product.</a>
```

Note the URL starts with `/`.

Comment: Hey man, thanks! That worked. I thought it had to be in a different folder.

Comment: Think you can help me here? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75728270/image-not-displaying-when-sent-to-database-nextjs